# How to change indexer mode from "update on save "to "update by schedule" from database or script Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, indexer

In Magento 2 admin panel I want to change indexer mode from **update on save** to **update by schedule** but I can not change it from the admin because it continues to loading nothing changes on any product related indexer.

I want to change this mode because in admin panel

> catalog -> product

section not loading. admin product page continues loading. and if after some time site giving 504 error at front-end and back-end.

So if anyone has any solution then let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Dhvanit, first of all you will need to check both the magento system/exception logs this will give people a better idea of what the issue could be also check your server error logs as could possibly be server related. id also recommend redeploying static content to make sure all JS and HTML has been loaded correctly.

Comment: you can change state using command also

Comment: @Rk Rathod  by command also it is not working i have tried that also

Comment: If there are any errors it is less likley that the index will work until its fixed please can you check the error logs to make sure.

Comment: @Dava Gordon I have checked log files and report but there is not any error.

Comment: Disable all indexes and activate one by one and see if they all index on there own

Comment: Thanks all now my issue is resolved